# Pass a data.table and a variable into a function

Tags: r, function

I am just started learning data science and I have a question that is probably easy for you. 
I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame(id= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),y = rnorm(9), x1 = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 9 )], x2 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),c2 = rnorm(9))
df
#    id time     y      x1 x2     c2
# 1  1    1  0.6364831  A  0 -0.066480473
# 2  1    2  0.4476390  B  0  0.161372575
# 3  1    3  1.5113458  C  0  0.343956178
# 4  2    1  0.3532957  D  0  0.279987147
# 5  2    2  0.3401402  E  1 -0.462635393
# 6  2    3 -0.3160222  F  0  0.338454940
# 7  3    1 -1.3797158  G  1 -0.621169576
# 8  3    2  1.4026640  H  1 -0.005690801
# 9  3    3  0.2958363  I  1 -0.176488132
```

I am writing a function with multiple steps. I would like the feed the function with two elements: the dataset and the variable of interest.

However, the function breaks down in an intermediate step, when I try to filter my data using data table. The crucial step of the function looks something like this.

```
testfun<- function(dataset,var){
  intermediatedf<-unique(setDT(dataset)[var==1 & c2>0,.(y)])
return(intermediatedf)
}
```

However, running the `df2<-testfun(df,y)` breaks down.

Can anyone help me and explain how can I create a function where I index both a dataset and a variable?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substitute` and `eval`

```
testfun <- function(dataset, var) {
    var <- substitute(var)
    intermediatedf <- unique(dataset[eval(var) == 1 & c2 > 0, .(y)])
    return(intermediatedf)
}
```